# связать бот телеграм с сайтом

Tags: telegram, бот

Добрый день, решил написать бота, да вот не знаю как. Бот который будет отправлять расписание студентам университета. Суть работы такая: пользователь вводит название группы, а бот ему отправляет расписание. Расписание на сайте, не знаю как связать бота с сайтом, там надо выбрать группу из списка и загружается расписание, можно ли и как сделать, чтобы бот сам брал расписание для группы (веденной пользователем) и выводил его в телеграме? Объясните подробно, т.к я только начинаю, заранее спасибо)

Comment: Нужно больше информации. На чем вы пишите бота? На php, node.js или может на Go? Или еще не определились?

Comment: Что значит "расписание на сайте" ? оно там в БД или прямо в статических html вбито. если первое - то бот должен просто брать из той же БД что и сайт. если в html или еще где - то отдельно сделать что то что соберет информацию с сайта и загрузит в БД, а бот опять же будет просто брать из базы

Answer (score -1):

Для начала тебе нужен парсер(код который собирает инфу с сайта) пример: https://habrahabr.ru/post/252379/

---

дальше отправлять данные полученне из парсера

Comment: Если расписание лежит не в виде статический страниц этот пример бесполезен так как напрямую из базы данных брать удобней и выгодней.